# Merging two data frames of different length by group id

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge two data frames by group id. However, both data frames are not of the same length and some elements of certain groups are missing in the second data frame. In the merged file, the missing elements of a certain group should be NAs.

The data looks something like this

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4), x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,3,4), y = c("A", "B", "D", "E", "G"))
```

Ideally, the result would look like this:

```
id  x    y
1   a    A
1   b    B
1   c <NA>
2   d    D
3   e    E
3   f <NA>
4   g    G
```

It would be great if the code worked for additional columns that also correspond to the same group ids but may miss elements at different places.

I have tried `full_join` and `merge` so far but without success, as they just repreat the y values instead of introducing na's.

I know there are similar questions out there, but I have found none that solves this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When joining on `id`, how would R get to know that one time id = 1 --> y = A, and the other time id = 1 --> Y = B... Is there some relation between x and y?

Comment: Not explicity, that is the problem. This is the result of some manipulations I did beforehand and technically all that links the two is how they are sorted. So if group 1 consists of x = a,b,c, then any non-missing values in y will necessarily be in the same order. Only the last n values of a certain group can me missing.

Comment: not a duplicate, because some data-preparation is needed befor joining. The actual join is not the problem/question here.

Comment: Maybe you can explain the process better. All I'm seeing is that you're matching lowercase letters in x with their uppercase versions in y, if those uppercase versions are present. Is there more to it? Or could you just add a lowercase version to y, and left-join on ID and lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `data.table` solution might work..

first, create row_id's per group. The  join by id on these row id's.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4), x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"))
dt2 <- data.table(id = c(1,1,2,3,4), y = c("A", "B", "D", "E", "G"))

#rumber rows by group
dt1[ , row_id := seq.int(1:.N), by = .(id)]
dt2[ , row_id := seq.int(1:.N), by = .(id)]

dt1[dt2, y := i.y, on = .(id, row_id)][, row_id := NULL][]

#    id x    y
# 1:  1 a    A
# 2:  1 b    B
# 3:  1 c <NA>
# 4:  2 d    D
# 5:  3 e    E
# 6:  3 f <NA>
# 7:  4 g    G
```

Comment: updated answer based on comments

Comment: also thanks for introducing me to data.tables, what an amazing package!